# How to print text and certain specified tags of XML file using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup, ms-word

I'm parsing the XML of a Microsoft Word .docx file with BeautifulSoup. I'd like to be able to extract the text of the XML file while still printing certain tags that I choose.

I can get the text of the file easily with `soup.text`

So for example, for the following XML content, `soup.text` would output `Here is some text inserted into a documente`

```
<w:body>
    <w:p>
        <w:r>
            <w:t>Here is some text</w:t>
        </w:r>
    
        <w:pPr>
        <w:spacing w:line="480" w:lineRule="auto"/>
            <w:jc w:val="center"/>
        </w:pPr>
    
        <w:ins w:id="2" w:author="Author">
            <w:r>
                <w:t>inserted</w:t>
            </w:r>
        </w:ins>
    
        <w:spacing w:line="480" w:lineRule="auto"/>
    
        <w:jc w:val="center"/>
    
        <w:r w:rsidRPr="00406F87">
            <w:t>into a document</w:t>
        </w:r>
    
        <w:del w:id="4" w:author="Author">
            <w:r w:rsidRPr="00406F87" w:rsidDel="00B30E79">
                <w:delText>e</w:delText>
            </w:r>
        </w:del>
    </w:p>
</w:body>
```

However, I want the output to also include the `<w:ins>` and `<w:del>` tags as well. So it would look like this:

```
Here is some text <w:ins>inserted</w:ins> into a document<w:del>e</w:del>
```

Is there a way to accomplish this with Beautiful Soup? I've also considered just writing a regular expression to remove all the tags except the ones I want, but I'd like to see if Beautiful Soup can do this first.

I've tried finding the answer by looking at the bs4 documentation as well as other posts on StackOverflow, but I'm coming up short.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Why not use `python-docx` to manipulate word documents?

Comment: @Hermann12 I'm not as familiar with `python-docx`--just read a bit about it. My understanding is it's used to create and edit Word files, not necessarily parse the XML of existing `.docx` files. Is it possible to output the text of a file with any deletions and insertions marked in XML tags using that library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

xml_doc = '''\
<w:body>
    <w:p>
        <w:r>
            <w:t>Here is some text</w:t>
        </w:r>

        <w:pPr>
        <w:spacing w:line="480" w:lineRule="auto"/>
            <w:jc w:val="center"/>
        </w:pPr>

        <w:ins w:id="2" w:author="Author">
            <w:r>
                <w:t>inserted</w:t>
            </w:r>
        </w:ins>

        <w:spacing w:line="480" w:lineRule="auto"/>

        <w:jc w:val="center"/>

        <w:r w:rsidRPr="00406F87">
            <w:t>into a document</w:t>
        </w:r>

        <w:del w:id="4" w:author="Author">
            <w:r w:rsidRPr="00406F87" w:rsidDel="00B30E79">
                <w:delText>e</w:delText>
            </w:r>
        </w:del>
    </w:p>
</w:body>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_doc, 'html.parser')

for t in soup.find_all(['w:ins', 'w:del']):
    t.replace_with(BeautifulSoup(f'<{t.name}>&lt;{t.name}&gt;{t.text.strip()}&lt;/{t.name}&gt;</{t.name}>', 'html.parser'))

print(soup.get_text(strip=True, separator=' '))
```

Prints:

```html
Here is some text <w:ins>inserted</w:ins> into a document <w:del>e</w:del>
```